# What library do I need to reference for remote connection to RDC server from console app?

Tags: c#, remoting, .net-remoting

We have a terminal server: "server.host.com". Normally, we RDP into that server for our business applications. However, I am performing some datamining and want to bring the .xml files to a local system for post processing.

My utility app would basically log in (impersonating my account), navigate to the directory where the .xml files are stored, then begin copying to a local directory. This utility would be set to run every morning at 3am unattended.

I am trying to determine whether WMI is the correct library, or Remoting, or some other library? Is this even going to be possible?

Comment: Can you not setup a shared folder on the server to provide secured access to the files you need?

Comment: @Bernard: not sure that I can set up a shared folder. The only way we connect to these servers is by URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are looking at using Microsoft's remote desktop, you can add a reference to Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type Library in the COM section. If you are working with a gui, you can just drag the control and do something like:

```
rdp.Server = txtServ.Text;
rdp.UserName = txtUser.Text;
IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPassword.Text;
rdp.Connect();
```

If you are using the console, should be just as simple just without the buttons and all.

Comment: this.rdp = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting(); would make the object.

Comment: Finally, got some progress. I was actually having problems getting the correct library reference. I'll let you know how it's going.

Comment: okay, if the remote server is "server.hosting.com", will this work? I am getting an invalid activeX state exception.